# Printing two def function side by side Python 3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am supposed to write a module that converts meters to feet and feet to meters using a defined function in Python 3. It should display like this:

```
Feet       Meters       |    Meters       Feet

1.0         .305        |    20.0          65.574
2.0         .610        |    26.0          81.967
...
9.0         2.745       |    60.0          196.721
10.0        3.050       |    66.0          213.115
```

I'm supposed to be using two functions:

```
def footToMeters(foot):
```

and

```
def meterToFoot(meter):
```

The code that I have right now is this:

```
foot = 1
meter = 20

def footToMeter(foot):
    meters = foot * .305
    print("Feet \t Meters")
    for foot in range(1,11):
        print(foot, "\t", meters)
        foot +=1
        meters = foot * .305


print()

def meterToFoot(meter):
    feet = round((meter/.305),3)
    print("Meters \t Feet")
    for meter in range(20,69,6):
        print(meter, "\t", feet)
        meter += 6
        feet = round((meter/.305),3)


print(footToMeter(foot))
print(meterToFoot(meter))
```

Obviously the last two print statements simply print the two functions one after the other.

My question is how do I get the two functions two print side by side?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Please consider shortening your question and have a look [here](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/2019688/python-101-unit-2-formatted-printing-and-function-documentation) and [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invert your code: the functions should simply take an input and return an output, then be called from a loop that prints values.

For example:

```
def footToMeter(foot):
    return foot * .305

print("Feet \t Meters")
for foot in range(1,11):
    print(foot, "\t", footToMeter(foot))
```

Comment: That actually makes sense haha! Thanks a ton. But I'm still confused on how to get them to print side by side

Comment: Your loop would simply have lines like `print(i, footToMeter(i), i+25, footToMeter(i+25))`. That is, it's up to you to determine which values to put in each column: there's no pre-defined function that does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code, but you need to make sure both two tables have the same number of rows.

Notice I changed meter's ranges from `range(20, 69, 6)` to `range(20, 75, 6)`

btw I don't have python3, so try change it to python3 yourself:)

```
foot = 1
meter = 20


def footToMeter(foot):
    return foot * .305


def meterToFoot(meter):
    return round((meter/.305),3)


print "Feet \t Meters |\t Meters \t Feet"
for foot, meter in zip(range(1, 11), range(20, 75, 6)):
    print ("%s \t %s \t|\t %s \t %s" 
            % (foot, footToMeter(foot), meter, meterToFoot(meter)))
```

Comment: Thank you shengy. Can you explain what the %s is doing?

Comment: Lets say the equal python3 statement would be `print(foot, footToMeter(foot), "\t|\t", meter, meterToFoot(meter))` wish there is no typos:). About `%s`, you can google `python string formatting expressions`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use special escape sequences like [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) the print statement (like old typewriters) writes text on the console from left to right, breaking to the next line after the last char or at the last screen column.

To make things work as you want, you must treat the units conversion and the printing problem separately. Your conversion functions should only return the converted value. Then you can deal with the printing and formatting on another code block or function.

Here is the code that should work as you expect, using string formatting for a better result:

```
def footToMeter(foot):
    return foot * .305

def meterToFoot(meter):
    return meter / .305

# printing the header
print "Feet\tMeters\t|\tMeters\tFeet\n"

# printing the values
feet, meters = 1, 20
for i in range(1, 11):
    print "%0.3f\t%0.3f\t|\t%0.3f\t%0.3f" % (feet, footToMeter(feet), meters, meterToFoot(meters))
    feet += 1
    meters += 4 + i % 2 * 2
```